# Use Picker View for navigation?

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I would like to use a picker view to navigate to different ViewControllers

The person scrolls to the name he wants in this case lets say Sony, then he pushes a button, and then it takes him to a view controller assigned for Sony. And so on..

I followed a video on Youtube that gave the code i will post below, The tutorial i followed created a alert view that simply tells you what you picked. I would like to replace this for a simple link to another ViewController.

Can someone please walk me through how to do this? I am a beginner and am trying to learn the best I can and can't seem to understand this.

Where i think i need to add code is at the bottom in slashes

```
.h:

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource>


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *Picker;

- (IBAction)ButtonPressed:(id)sender;

@end




.m:

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()



@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *array;
@end





@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];


NSArray *data = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Apple",@"Samsung", @"HTC", @"LG", @"Google", @"Asus", @"Nokia", @"Sony", nil];


self.array = data;

}


#pragma mark Picker Data Source Methods

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {


return 1;

}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {

return [_array count];

}

#pragma mark Picker Delegate Methods

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {


return [_array objectAtIndex:row];


}




/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)ButtonPressed:(id)sender {


NSString *select = [_array objectAtIndex:[_Picker selectedRowInComponent:0]];

NSString *tittle = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"You selected %@:", select];

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:tittle message:@"YAY!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];



[alert show];


}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
@end
```

Comment: For those who feel it necessary to down-vote this question: Quit picking on the new guy. Everyone starts somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

First off - I think you should consider using a UITableView instead of a UIPicker for navigation. UITableView is kind of the standard, and users may find navigation via UIPicker view a little confusing. Either way, rather than try to explain everything here, I recommend you go look at some of these suuuuper helpful tutorials from a benevolent iOS guru: Ray Wenderlich.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials

Since the kind of navigation you are talking about doing is pretty standard to most apps, it's very likely (in fact, I can pretty much guarantee it) that you will find a solution for what you're trying to do within the first few tutorials. Especially, go take a look at the "How to create a simple iPhone app" series (which is right there on that link I posed above). You'll find a wealth of knowledge in there that will help immensely as you cut your teeth on iOS programming.

So, good luck and welcome to iOS!

Comment: Woah!!! This is awesome man thank you so much! I now have better ideas just looking through it. And finding the tuts very helpfull. Thanks alot!